# Keep User logged when browser is restarted

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

For logout purposes, after session timeout, I’m using this piece of code

```
if (context.Session.IsNewSession)
{
     string sessionCookie = context.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
     if ((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
     {
          var controller = (BaseController)filterContext.Controller;
          var routeValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Account", action = "SessionLogOff", area = string.Empty });
          filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValueDictionary);
      }
}
```

That is implemented in OnActionExecuting as ActionFilterAttribute.

I am using ASPNet Identity 2.2 and MVC 5.2.

This works well, when a session expires and Session.IsNewSession is true.

My problem is when browser is restarted, the application starts and the user already exists (cookie), the Session.IsNewSession is true and that user is logged out in the first action he tries to execute.

Comment: Well, the application doesn't start. The browser re-starts but the application knows nothing about that. All it knows is there is a request being made that doesn't have a session cookie. Session cookies are meant not to be stored in cache so they are in-memory. When the browser closes, that cookie goes away also. This is pretty much how every system does session.  I would say avoid tying session with user login since you can do things to persists user logins separately and extend their lifespan where session is extremely vulnerable for re-starts.

Comment: @Rui Rodrigues, Are you using `ASP.NET Identity`?

Comment: asp.net identity version 2.2.1